# How to boot USB 3.0 in VMWare?

Tags: boot, usb, vmware, usb-3

How would I go about booting a USB 3.0 drive (connected to a USB 3.0 port) in VMware 11.1.2 (build 2780323)? It's an Arch Linux installation.

I have enabled USB 3.0 support in the USB Controller settings. The correct drive is connected to the VM.

I have already tried:

- Plop - won't transfer to the Syslinux installation on the USB drive. What it shows:

  ```
  Loading EHCI Driver
  Searching On Hosts
  Host 1
  Driver Removed
  Loading DHCI Driver
  Searching On Hosts
  Host 1
  Port 2: Device Connected
  No HD
  Driver Removed
  Loading DHCI Driver
  Searching On Hosts
  Driver Removed
  Boot Error
  No Boot Device Found, Please Retry It
  ```

  Apparently, Plop doesn't support USB 3.0.
- plopkexec - Doesn't show bootup option. Log:

  ```
  Cannot mount /dev/sda
  New device sda1
  Mounted /dev/sda1, ext4 (ro)
  Scanning /mnt/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg
  Default arch
  Timeout 50  -1
  Timeout 1   32
  Label arch
  Menu label Arch Linux
  Append root=UUID={x} rw earlymodules=xhci_hcd modules-load=xhci_hcd
  Initrd ../initramfs-linux.img
  Label archfallback
  Menu label Arch Linux Fallback
  Append root=UUID={x} rw earlymodules=xhci_hcd modules-load=xhci_hcd
  Initrd ../initramfs-linux-fallback.img
  Label hdt
  Menu label HDT
  Label reboot
  Menu label reboot
  Label poweroff
  Menu label Poweroff
  Set cursor position: 0, arch
  ```

where {x} is the UUID of the partition.

- Hard Drive as Physical Drive - Basically, this involves creating a hard drive and selecting the Physical Drive option, but after a while, it always gives me an error, and the only way to fix it is to reset the VM. (I don't have the error right now, if I get it I'll edit this post.)

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of VMWare specifically?

Comment: VMware 11.1.2 build 2780323.

Comment: Update the question so these comments can be removed.